# Angular 5 pass additional values as query parameters

Tags: angular

In `formNavigation.ts` (shared module component) I have:

```
@Input nextPath?:string

next() {
    this.router.navigate([this.nextPath], {queryParamsHandling: "merge"})
}
```

In `comp1.component.html`:

```
<form-navigation [nextPath]="'enroll/plans'"></form-navigation>
```

The above code is working fine, I am fetching query params through activated route in enroll/plans page.

But I want to pass an additional value(index = 0) as query params

```
<form-navigation [nextPath]="'enroll/plans'" {index:0}></form-navigation>
```

I tried above code to send index = 0 to enroll/plans but it's showing an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

first of all if you want to pass query params you have to do this

```
this.router.navigate([this.nextPath], { queryParams: { x : val} } );
```

then define `Input` for params, and bind it in your html.

so your final code will look like this

```
@Input() index: number;

this.router.navigate([this.nextPath], { queryParams: { index : this.index} } );

<form-navigation nextPath="enroll/plans" [index]="0"></form-navigation>
```

Comment: this.router.navigate([this.nextPath], { queryParams: { index : this.index}, {queryParamsHandling: "merge"} } );??

Comment: btw why do you need queryParamsHandling?